# No Bluetooth Found - Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: bluetooth

Computer : Vivobook 17 Asus X705m

I used to have windows on this computer, occasionally, the bluetooth would stop working. I would uninstall drivers and restart computer. Problem solved.

For a while I was dual booting, Ubuntu and windows. Bluetooth would stop working in Linux. I solved by booting into Windows and using above solution, then booting into Linux where bluetooth was working again.

I removed windows and did clean Ubuntu install. Bluetooth working fine. I'm pretty sure that bluetooth would stop working when I would leave home with my comp and use my phone to tether to the internet.

So, again, bluetooth not working and I can't get it working again.

I've seen this question asked a few times here and I've tried some solutions but no success.

Bluez gives the following message:
Connection to BlueZ failed
Bluez daemon is not running, blueman-manager cannot continue.
This probably means that there were no bluetooth adapters detected or Bluetooth daemon was not started.

The following shows on startup screen. I don't know if it is connected but these messages only started appearing after bluetooth stopped for last time.

```
2.083245] usb 1-8: device descriptor read/64, error -71
2.319134] usb 1-8: device descriptor read/64, error -71
2.683209] usb 1-8: device descriptor read/64, error -71
2.919136] usb 1-8: device descriptor read/64, error -71
4.095133] usb 1-8: device not accepting address 5, error -71
4.639133] usb 1-8: device not accepting address 6, error -71
4.639399] usb usb1-port8: unable to enumerate usb device
//sda2: clean, 239969/61022208 file, 885390/244059287 blocks
21.074680] mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
```

*Edited to add:*

Sorry for the delay in getting back.
As advised, I replaced the blue tooth card and now everything is working as it should.
Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: There is a good chance the Bluetooth device has finally died and has been dying for quite a while. Have you tried to use a Bluetooth USB device to confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a network card which is both WiFi- and Bluetooth-enabled, I would suggest trying a different network card to see if it would still give you such issue, or removing the network card from your PC, cleaning it and putting it back.

Otherwise, try using an external Bluetooth dongle to see if the problem persists.

Also, make sure to update your system packages using `sudo apt update` and upgrade with `sudo apt -y upgrade`. Could be that you're using an outdated package or there's no package for your Bluetooth dongle.

Hope this helps.